# Routing error on Heroku with assets that are no longer even used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I changed the code on the page at my root path months ago (and many deploys ago, and many rake assets:clean and assets:precompile's ago) but I keep getting this error in my logs on an almost daily basis:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/old_time_investor-8fbf5492bd22cc620b0208f84af82a6c.jpg")

That image file is no longer referenced anywhere in my code.  What might still be trying to use this image file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your site has been crawled by an image search engine which has remembered that path and is trying to refresh it.  I've seen that kind of thing before.  yandex.com used to hit my site a lot like this.

Do you catch your exceptions with AirBrake or similar?  If it catches that exception, take a loot at the exception's environment to see where the request came from.  If there is a HTTP_REFERRER or USER_AGENT or IP address, that may give you a clue.

Of if you don't have an exception aggregator, just look at your Heroku log for a `heroku[router]` line near the exception, then Google the IP address of that line and see where it came from.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked up the IP address for one of the routing errors and it said it came from LinkedIn Corporation.  Is LinkedIn crawling my site for some reason?  The 2nd error I looked up came from MSNBot, which obviously is a crawler.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a link in one of your views that references that image. This error should also appear in development environment so I suggest debug from there for immediate feedback.

Comment: It had been completely removed from the views months ago